# Python - Selenium - Select Dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select a dropdown box.
The code from the page is:

```
<span class="sui-dropdown" tabindex="0" style="width: 150px;">
<select class="dropdown-soberanos-plazo" style="display: none;">
<option value="CI">CI</option><option value="24hs">24hs</option>
<option value="48hs">48hs</option>
</select>
<span class="sui-input sui-unselectable" unselectable="on">48hs</span>
<span class="sui-caret-container sui-unselectable" unselectable="on">
<span class="sui-caret sui-unselectable" unselectable="on">
</span></span></span>
```

I tried the next code, but i am not even able to select the dropdown.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="soberanos"]/div/div[3]/span')
Out[176]: [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f181c2e9094dce7159f3b24212735c16", element="8846fda9-7cbe-4b20-ae8c-6b6071f7a18f")>]

Select(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="soberanos"]/div/div[3]'))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22996\2906900798.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    Select(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="soberanos"]/div/div[3]'))

  File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\Selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 36, in __init__
    if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

and

```
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

with no success :(

I tried with diferents XPATH, same result.

```
Select(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="soberanos"]/div/div[3]/span/select'))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ltaboada\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22996\1364519513.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    Select(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="soberanos"]/div/div[3]/span/select'))

  File "C:\Users\ltaboada\Desktop\Selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 36, in __init__
    if webelement.tag_name.lower() != "select":

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

So....
any advice?
thanks!!!
[dropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSq77.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your added `code` and `HTML` I can give you the idea, try the below ***Solution***.

`driver.find_elements` returns list of `WebElements`.

It should be `driver.find_element`. Note the `s` in `find_element.`

So, the line of code should be like

```
Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="soberanos"]/div/div[3]'))
```

Let us know if this does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!!!
I finally made it!
I used a diferent XPATH

```
dropbox_menu_principal=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="topNav"]/div/div[1]/button/i')))
dropbox_menu_principal.click()
```

and for the internal buttons i used the Link_Text Opción.

```
    if(type(menues)==str):
    menu=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,menues)))
    menu.click()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).